# Css text paragraph align

Tags: css

i want to display text where text begins first line for second line also, but it is going left side under numbers pls help

1 Text line paragraph and and 
and and and and and
  and and and and and
2 Text line paragraph and and 
and and and and and
  and and and and and
3 Text line paragraph and and 
 and and and and and
  and and and and and

Note: without using list class i want this type of display text with css please help.

Comment: Are the numbers part of content, or should they be generated with CSS? What do you mean by “list class”? (`ol` element?)

Comment: yes, numbers also part of content, but text part will be display  where first line text (not number) starts. i have no idea how to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the indentation you are after you could just do this:

```
p {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -0.75em;
}
```

Depending on font you may have to adjust the `text-indent` value a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/h7KvC/

Comment: The essential flaw of this answer is in the words “Depending on font”. The total width of text consisting of a digit, a period, and a space is strongly font-dependent. Besides, if there are more than one digit, things get even more different.

Comment: That's a good point, but without changing the structure this is probably the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that for text consisting of numbered items where the numbers are part of the content, each item should start on a new line and the second and subsequent lines of an item should be left-aligned to the same point where the text proper (after number, period, and space) of the first line starts. I also assume that “without using list class” means that the element for a numbered list, `ol`, must not be used, for some reason.

The simplest (and most robust) solution is then to use a table. Example:

```
<style>
table.list { border-collapse: collapse; }
table.list td { padding: 0; vertical-align: top; }
table.list td:first-child { text-align: right; padding-right: 0.25em; }
</style>
<table class=list>
<tr><td>1.</td><td>Text line paragraph and and and and and and and and and and and and</td></tr>
<tr><td>2.</td><td>Text line paragraph and and and and and and and and and and and and</td></tr>
<tr><td>3.</td><td>Text line paragraph and and and and and and and and and and and and</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you need avoid using `table` markup, then you need to simulate it somehow, e.g. using `div` and `span` markup and CSS table formatting (`display: table` etc.) – works in modern browsers, but not in old versions of IE.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bQWau/3/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you explain how to display using div and span with out table.

Comment: @user1887288, I don’t see any good reason to avoid using a table here, but that would mean using e.g. `div` instead of `table`, `div class=row` instead of `tr`, and `span class=cell` instead of `td`, and settig `display` to `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell`, respectively. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kquxY/

Comment: Nothing wrong with tables but i am doing work digital publications so client need without table.

Answer (score 0):

Use text-indent and clear both in css hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: hi, but not worked second line of text going under number i have used this css as per u r help{font-size:1em; text-indent:1em; clear:both;}

Answer (score 0):

Make a ol out of it..

```
<ol>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

**Result :**

1. Text line paragraph and and
    
   and and and and and and and and and and
2. Text line paragraph and and
    
   and and and and and and and and and and
3. Text line paragraph and and
    
   and and and and and and and and and and

Comment: But i need with out using li ol ul, instead of i want div and p , span

Answer (score -1):

You can make paragraphs into list items in this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
  <p>Paragraph one</p>
  <p>Paragraph two</p>
  <p>Paragraph three</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list {
  counter-reset: pcount;
}
.list p:before {
  counter-increment: pcount;
  content: counter(pcount, decimal) ' ';
}
```

**Result**

> ```
> 1 Paragraph one
> 2 Paragraph two
> 3 Paragraph three
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/bQWau/1/

Comment: Agreed. I thought it was the numbering OP was after. Some additional info was added later.